как запустить код на Go?

Я скачал golang, и не понимаю как запустить код. Заранее спасибо

Стоит поискать литературу или курс начального уровня по GO. В видео всё будет показано на пальцах

go run main.go

Ctrl+F5 работает? Вообще, смотрите меню Run.

Убедиться в том что Go установлен и работает из консоли. И как написал Jour, за исключением того, что скрипт задавшего вопрос называется first.go, выполнить команду
go run first.go

Но вообще ответ находится на раз два: https://golang-blog.blogspot.com/2019/04/go-for-scripts.html
